# Add data to the bottom of a range

Tags: google-apps-script

So I'm currently trying to set up a simple button which moves data from a range into another sheet for future reference. I've got it working if the sheet it is going to contains no information but I wanted to put all of the references into one sheet together.

Is there a way to add to the bottom of a range of data? This is what I have at the moment.

```
function Addvoucher() {
            var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
            var target_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Meta');
            var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tools");
            var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("B9:D9");
            var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("S3:U3");
                        
            var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
            
          var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("S3" + (last_row + 1) + ":U3" + (last_row + 1));
          
            target_sheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);
          
            source_range.copyTo(target_range);

}
```

Comment: `destSh.getRange(destSh.getLastRow()+1,1,numrows,numcols).....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I think that in your script, how about modifying `"S3" + (last_row + 1) + ":U3" + (last_row + 1)` of `target_sheet.getRange("S3" + (last_row + 1) + ":U3" + (last_row + 1))` as follows?
- In the current script, for example, `last_row + 1` is `2`, `"S3" + (last_row + 1) + ":U3" + (last_row + 1)` becomes `S32:U32`. In this case, it is required to be `S2:U2`. I think that this might be the reason of your issue.
- > Tried this, the issue is there is data in other columns to the left of this "block" of information thus this gets put onto row 100 as its the first available row.

  - From your replying, I could understand that in your Spreadsheet, the columns except for the columns "U" to "S" has the values and the last row of the columns "U" to "S" is different from other columns.

When above points as reflected to your script, I would like to propose to modify as follows.

#### From:

```
var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("S3" + (last_row + 1) + ":U3" + (last_row + 1));
```

#### To:

```
var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
var values = target_sheet.getRange("S1:U" + last_row).getValues();
for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (values[i].every(e => e.toString() != "")) {
    last_row = i + 1;
    break;
  }
}
var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("S" + (last_row + 1) + ":U" + (last_row + 1));
```

Comment: Tried this, the issue is there is data in other columns to the left of this "block" of information thus this gets put onto row 100 as its the first available row.

Comment: @liam gore Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your question, I couldn't notice that in your Spreadsheet, the columns except for the columns "U" to "S" has the values and the last row of the columns "U" to "S" is different from other columns. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: Code is returning a syntax error on the if (values[i].every(e => e.toString() != "")) { line

Comment: @liam gore Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I thought that in your situation, you might not enable V8 runtime at the script editor. If it's so, please enable V8 and test it again. If you don't want to use V8, please modify it to `values[i].every(function(e) {return e.toString() != ""})`.

Comment: Thats perfect! its working great!
Time to tidy up my meta page :)

Comment: @liam gore Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.